# TypeError when calling setProps on shallow Enzyme wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, enzyme

I'm getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null` when trying to call `setProps` on an enzyme wrapper of a pure React component.

I wrote a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, the test looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {shallow} from "enzyme"

import Simple from "../Simple"

describe("<Simple />", () => {
  it("renders param", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Simple param="foo" />)

    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual("foo")
    wrapper.setProps({param: "bar"})
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual("bar")
  })
})
```

and this is the component:

```
export default function Simple(props) {
  return props.param
}
```

I'm on React `16.0.0-alpha.12`, React Native `0.46.4` and Enzyme `2.9.1`

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme doesn't yet support React 16, as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/928) at the time of writing.

Unfortunately, since React Native 0.43 and higher requires React 16, React Native and and Enzyme are currently not compatible.

Whether or not your particular issue is caused by this incompatibility, you'll likely find that Enzyme won't work for you.

In the meantime, you may be best off by using [Jest snapshot tests](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/snapshot-testing.html) instead of assertion tests.